# Add an extra row to grade table in exam class

Tags: exam, gradetable

Consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question [10] First question text.
  \question [20] Second question text.
\end{questions}

\gradetable[h]

\end{document}
```

I would like to add another row (say for signature of graders to individual questions) to the grade table that is generated.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can accomplish that by grossly abusing the `\combinedgradetable` command, as in:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \question [10] First question text.
  \question [20] Second question text.
\end{questions}

\begingroup
  \chbpword{Signature:}
  \settabletotalbonuspoints{}
  \renewcommand{\bonuspointsofquestion}[1]{}
  \combinedgradetable[h]
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

The `\chbpword` command replaces the text `Bonus points:` with `Signature`, the `\settabletotalbonuspoints` command causes the box for the total bonus points to be left empty, and the `renewcommand` causes the boxes for the bonus points of each question to be left empty.

Comment: Before posting the question I was getting the rough idea that I have to hack into the tables which provide an extra row. But failed to achieve it. You have done it. Thanks a lot. Is there any way to make the signature row the last row?

Comment: @Masroor: see next answer. BTW, hacking the table generating code is not easy.

Comment: @PhilHirschhorn: why are the `\begingroup`and `endgroup` needed?

Comment: @Jesse op den Brouw: The grouping is to keep the commands just before the table command from affecting any other tables in the document.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
\begingroup
  \chbpword{Score:}
  \chsword{Signature:}
  \settabletotalbonuspoints{}
  \renewcommand{\bonuspointsofquestion}[1]{}
  \combinedgradetable[h]
\endgroup
```

reverses the Score and Signature names so that Signature is on the bottom row.