# How do you remove exam's total points column (or row) from the `gradetable`?

Tags: exam

I use the `exam` class to typeset a test paper and produce the gradetable with a call to `\gradetable[h]`. It prints the question number and the total points as expected, but I want the column with the number of total points gone, i.e. the column on the right here:
[image: sample gradetable generated by the exam documentclass]
Generated by this MWE (a second run would get the numbers right...):

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\begin{document}
\gradetable[h][questions]
\begin{questions}
\question[1]
\question[2]
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Never mind me asking why I want to do this:
I have a lot of questions and they need to fit in one row. Secondly I will print the number of total points somewhere else in the document.

---

The package documentation does not mention this feature. The only remotely related question I found is [about how to add a row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/445712/add-an-extra-row-to-grade-table-in-exam-class/445721#445721), not to remove one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This patch will remove the last column from horizontal tables.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
    
% ******************************** added <<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@computenumcols@h}
{\addtocounter{num@cols}{2}}
{\addtocounter{num@cols}{1}}
{}{}
\makeatother
% ********************************

\begin{document}
    \gradetable[h][questions]
    
    \begin{questions}
        \question[1]
        \question[2]
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'll look into `xpatch`, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create a customized grade table that doesn't have total points in it:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\cgradetable}{%
  \begin{raggedright}
    \textbf{Grade Table:}\\
    \begin{tabular}{|l*{5}{|c}|}
        \hline
        Question & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
        \hline
        Points & \pointsofquestion{1} & \pointsofquestion{2} & 
        \pointsofquestion{3} & \pointsofquestion{4} & 
        \pointsofquestion{5} \\
        \hline
        Score &&&&&\\ 
        \hline
        
    \end{tabular}
  \end{raggedright}
 }

\begin{document}

\cgradetable

\begin{questions}
    \question[1] Question 1
    \question[4] Question 2
    \question[10] Question 3
    \question[8] Question 4
    \question[7] Question 5
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But this means I would have to update the gradetable every time the number of questions changes.